# Warning AL1073 when generating satellite assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, localization, compiler-warnings, satellite-assembly

Under Visual Studio 2010, I am getting a compiler warning when generating a localized satellite assembly for a project.  I am running Windows 7 64-bit.

The project is being built in x86 (it has to be as it indirectly references an unmanaged DLL - via Oracle ODP.NET).

The MSBuild log generates the following warning:

> (GenerateSatelliteAssemblies target) ->
>
> ALINK : warning AL1073: Referenced assembly 'mscorlib.dll' targets a different processor [xxx.csproj]

Is there any way to force this to use the same version of the framework as the assembly it is being generated from?

It is very frustrating as I like to have zero warnings in our build, and this is always there.

Comment: Did you try using the x86 version of MSBuild, that is the one located in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 and not in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319?

Comment: No I didn't. I will try forcing TFS to use the x86 platform. But how can I resolve this using my Visual Studio, as I also get this error there....

Comment: You can check the References node in your solution, check the properties of, say, System.dll, the path should be C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\... for x86 and C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\... for x64. Hope this will give you a clue.

Comment: Yeah this seems to have solved the problem in TFS...but not in VS2010.

Comment: But I shouldn't have to add different assembly references for the core libraries in different configurations should I?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't, but I just don't know how to tell VS to reference appropriate vesrions of core libraries depending on the active platform when it generates satellite assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced this error (by mistake).  My projects target x86 (because of 3rd party DLLs), but I ran MSBuild in VSx64 2010 command window.  That sets Platform=X64 among other things.
When I ran it under VS 2010 command window (for x86), I didn't get this warning.